# Software Updater not starting up

Tags: apt, software-center, sudo, software-sources

So my original problem was that I couldn't get the ubuntu software centre to startup, it would just freeze for a while loading and then would crash.

So i tried to remove USC : Successfully

When I came to re-install I ran into a problem with the sudo-apt install / get and loads of other commands.

This is what i get when i enter sudo apt-get update

> E: Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

I looked into the folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and there seems to be no source list file, however there appears to be one in its parent folder.

I'm still new to this and I couldn't find a solution anywhere on the forums. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks !

Comment: read the error more closely, the file is in /etc/apt and the file name is sources.list

Comment: you are correct sire :)

Comment: if you add any ppas, each repository will have it's own file and each of these files will be found in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. You were right to assume that directory at first as it is more common for there to be a malformed file there because that's usually where extra non-supported repos are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a terminal and type the following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now, scroll down to line 56. There is your problem. What is different about this line? Is there a typo somewhere? Did you add this line manually?

To get around this problem, you can delete this line or comment it out by placing a <kbd>#</kbd> at the beginning of the line. After fixing the line, removing it, or commenting it out, save the file.

After saving the file run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

There should be no error anymore.

To apply updates, run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it mentions any packages held back, you can run this command to install them:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!

That seems to have solved my problem !! 

Bless you :) :p